# How can I steal the automaton's voice box without being seen, or catching an arrow to the knee?

Tags: thief

One of the side missions has you steal the voice box for the metal man, but the safe with the voice box in it is trapped.

It would seem that the only way to disable the trap lies in going to the top floor, but there's a couple of guards hanging around, making it difficult to sneak through undetected.

How do I get past the guard undetected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually the trickiest problem I've faced so far, playing the new Thief.

There's a ventilation shaft in the room next to the safe room, which leads back to the entrance with the stairs. You'll need to go through that shaft and exit it<sup>**1**</sup>. Stick close to the shaft entrance, or you'll be spotted by the guard.

Shoot a blunt arrow on the switch, by the staircase leading downstairs; this will turn off the lights and give you a good opportunity to sneak upstairs undetected.

You will obviously raise the guard's suspicion, but at least you won't be detected.

---

<sup>**1**</sup>: You might want to save beforehand.

Comment: But how did you get to the safe in the first place? If you come in from the basement, you can manually flip the switch and then jump over the railing as the guard comes around to turn it back on. (depending on difficulty)

Comment: @horatio I took the front entrance. Didn't know the hole lead to the basement until after I was there. I'm guessing there are a bunch of people who take the front door approach.

Comment: I got through it undetected in a similar way but there doesn't seem to be a way to do it without raising suspicion.

Answer (score 0):

you take the guard outside with a headshot from the balcony, shoot the dog, blunt arrow the big hanging crate then jump down in to the basement. Go up the basement stairs and wait until the 2nd guard walks away in to the other room. Headshot the guard from the stairs then flip the switch off and wait for the 2nd guard to walk back in. You need to headshot the 2nd guard before he realises what's going on. Then after you sneak upstairs and knock out Perry you're free to pillage and loot as you please.